# jQuery.on("drop") not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag and dropping of files from the desktop the browser window. I have used jQuery to attach three events to the HTML element as in the code below:

```
$("html").on("dragover", function() {
    $(this).addClass('dragging');
});

$("html").on("dragleave", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('dragging');
});

$("html").on("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("Dropped!");
});
```

The 'dragover' and 'dragleave' events work fine, displaying an inset border around the entire page when I drag a file over an removing it if I drag the file out again.

However, the 'drop' event doesn't seem to fire at all, the dropped file simply opens in the browser window.

Does anyone have any idea why this event is not firing?

Btw, I am testing this in the latest version of Chrome and using jQuery 1.10.2.

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339924/drop-event-not-firing-in-chrome/36207613#36207613

Comment: potential answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414154/html5-drop-event-doesnt-work-unless-dragover-is-handled

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You need to cancel all events

```
$("html").on("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('dragging');
});

$("html").on("dragleave", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass('dragging');
});

$("html").on("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("Dropped!");
});
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. Funny how that never actually occurred to me! I also had to remove the class on the 'drop' event as, when dropped, the 'dragleave' event won't get triggered.

Comment: For anyone following; its the additional cancel of "dragover" that causes the drop to then fire. Canceling dragenter and dragleave isn't enough. As @Christian says you have to cancel them ALL.

Comment: Can you please add explanation on why do I need to remove/cancel the CSS

Comment: If you mean the "$(this).removeClass('dragging')" statement, this is simply the OPs way of styling the page when dragging occurs. It has nothing to do with the drag-and-drop operation.

Comment: Since I ended here first with google, maybe have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339924/drop-event-not-firing-in-chrome) answer, and the referenced link to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#droptargets) with the explanation *why* u have to cancel the events!

Comment: @Kong: Thank you! This wasn't working for me at all until I read your comment. Now, finally, after hours of pain, it works! :)

Comment: Make sure you wait for the DOM to be loaded first. I didn't. Classic mistake.

Comment: Adding to @Lux comment, here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#specifying_drop_targets) to exact section that explains this.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to Christian's solution this can be shortened to:

```js
$('#my-dropzone')
    // crucial for the 'drop' event to fire
    .on('dragover', false) 

    .on('drop', function (e) {
        // do something
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: How can I get the element that was dragged on the drop zone? for example a file dragged to the zone?

Comment: 2020 and a single one-line comment in this answer saved me much trouble

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cancel any event. Just you can user event.preventDefault() for dragover and drop events:

```
$(document)
.on('dragover', '.target', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Do anything you want to do in dragover
})
.on('drop', '.target', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // You will catch this event here
})
```