# Drop event not firing in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, drag-and-drop, jquery-events

It seems the drop event is not triggering when I would expect.

I assume that the drop event fires when an element that is being dragged is releases above the target element, but this doesn't seem to the the case.

What am I misunderstanding?

http://jsfiddle.net/LntTL/

```
$('.drop').on('drop dragdrop',function(){
    alert('dropped');
});
$('.drop').on('dragenter',function(){
    $(this).html('drop now').css('background','blue');
})
$('.drop').on('dragleave',function(){
    $(this).html('drop here').css('background','red');
})
```

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223352/jquery-ondrop-not-firing/36207641#36207641

Comment: potential answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414154/html5-drop-event-doesnt-work-unless-dragover-is-handled

Answer (score 247, accepted):

In order to have the drop event occur on a div element, you must cancel the `ondragenter` and `ondragover` events.  Using jquery and your code provided...

```
$('.drop').on('drop dragdrop',function(){
    alert('dropped');
});
$('.drop').on('dragenter',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).html('drop now').css('background','blue');
})
$('.drop').on('dragleave',function(){
    $(this).html('drop here').css('background','red');
})
$('.drop').on('dragover',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

For more information, check out [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#droptargets).

Comment: You don't need ondragenter, only ondragover.

Comment: Still a no-go, at least when dragging images onto that on latest Chrome.

Comment: Still doesn't work on latest Chromium (Vivaldi  1.2.490.39 () (32-bit)
http://jsfiddle.net/f282n3pt/3/

Comment: With reactjs, you need to add onDragOver handler to the same elem.

Comment: Is html5 dnd API really THAT bad?

Comment: you do need ondragenter as of Chrome 62, as ondragover will only fire after subsequent mouse moves, thus you would not call e.preventDefault(), causing the drop event to sometimes not fire

Comment: btw, `preventDefault()` will not work when you use throttled function for `"dragover"`

Comment: Specifiging `dragover` works. HTML5 has too many inconsistencies like that. What if one has a full page "DROP HERE" target, hence you don't need the drag over event. Weird corner cases, instead of sticking to what each event should fo.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me, but the answer from Bob here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36207613/884177 resolved the problem.

Comment: dragover is neccessary to prevent default behaviour for drop event to work even if it shouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 71):

You can get away with just doing an `event.preventDefault()` on the `dragover` event. Doing this will fire the `drop` event.

Comment: that has an uncovered edge case, you must call e.preventDefault() on dragenter too, see my other comment

Answer (score 13):

In order for the drop event to fire, you need to assign a dropEffect during the over event, otherwise the ondrop event will never get triggered:

```
$('.drop').on('dragover',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';  // required to enable drop on DIV
})
// Value for dropEffect can be one of: move, copy, link or none
// The mouse icon + behavior will change accordingly.
```

Comment: Actually you need to do `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"` because jQuery uses its own `event`

Comment: This solution worked for me. After doing work around on this issue,  i think think this is necessary to prevent the default behavior of dragover event.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an actual answer but for some people like me who lack the discipline for consistency. Drop didn't fire for me in chrome when the `effectAllowed` wasnt the effect I had set for `dropEffect`. It did however work for me in Safari. This should be set like below:

`ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';`

Alternatively, `effectAllowed` can be set as `all`, but I would prefer to keep specificity where I can.

for a case when drop effect is move:

`ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';`