# Draggable is true - not draggable and DOM selectors are not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement **DargAndDrop** notion in my project, developed in "*Apriso Dassault Systemes*" - but once project is loaded on a browser, there are no differences between this one and the one developed on ASP and other technos.

The [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUGKH2J1WGPY) shows that it's feasible (but I used mostly [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/bcv3owx2/9/) `draggable`) but when it comes to my project, I'm having a hard time achieving it on the following things :

1. When item is **draggable** and when you try to drag it, only "not allowed" sign appears, you don't see your dragging element ;
2. I can not bind events (onDragStart, OnDrop etc) via DOM, I have to pass via javascript, even this doesn't work for **onDrop** event ;
3. onDragOver can't be bined and I have to use onDragStart where preventDefault() doesn't seem to be working, on hovering the same "not allowed" sign is shown ;

I would really appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: no one can help you if you don't post your code that shows what you've tried and the problems you're having.

Comment: I did post my code. Click the link in my question.

Comment: first link is a w3school example, 2nd link is not your code either. Put your code on JSFiddle or codepen

Comment: But I'm using those lines of code. There's nothing else in my code.
The point is, how to make this codes work in your project...

Comment: I found this, and it works.
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339924/drop-event-not-firing-in-chrome**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop event not firing in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339924/drop-event-not-firing-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

For having working with Apriso, I suggest you to put your javascript/JQuery code related to the DOM or a library inside the window load event.

```
$(window).load(function() {
})
```

Or at least inside the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
})
```

if your code is related to DOM only.