# Jquery drop not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I need to fire the drop part so that when user drop a file it uploads. But in my code drop not firing.

Please give me the corrected version of this code. This is really very important for my project. This code is taken from another **stackoverflow** post. And I have edited the drop part at the code given below.
User's answer will be appreciated.

```
$.fn.dndhover = function(options) {

    return this.each(function() {

        var self = $(this);
        var collection = $();

        self.on('dragenter', function(event) {
            if (collection.length === 0) {
                self.trigger('dndHoverStart');
            }
            collection = collection.add(event.target);
        });

        self.on('dragleave', function(event) {
            /*
             * Firefox 3.6 fires the dragleave event on the previous element
             * before firing dragenter on the next one so we introduce a delay
             */
            setTimeout(function() {
                collection = collection.not(event.target);
                if (collection.length === 0) {
                    self.trigger('dndHoverEnd');
                }
            }, 1);
        });

        self.on('drop', function(event) {
            alert(event);
            self.trigger('dndHoverDrop');
        });
    });
};

$('.uploadDiv').dndhover().on({
    'dndHoverStart': function(event) {

        if(!$(".selectFile").hasClass("hide")){
            $(".selectFile").addClass("hide");
        }
        if($(".dropFile").hasClass("hide")){
            $(".dropFile").removeClass("hide");
        }

        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    },
    'dndHoverEnd': function(event) {

        if($(".selectFile").hasClass("hide")){
            $(".selectFile").removeClass("hide");
        }
        if(!$(".dropFile").hasClass("hide")){
            $(".dropFile").addClass("hide");
        }

        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    },
    'dndHoverDrop': function(event) {
        alert('dropped');
        if(!$(".selectFile").hasClass("hide")){
            $(".selectFile").addClass("hide");
        }
        if(!$(".dropFile").hasClass("hide")){
            $(".dropFile").addClass("hide");
        }
        event.preventDefault();  
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

New Code:

```
$.fn.dndhover = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {

            var self = $(this);
            var collection = $();

            self.on('dragenter', function(event) {
                if (collection.length === 0) {
                    self.trigger('dndDragEnter');
                }
                collection = collection.add(event.target);
            });

            self.on('dragleave', function(event) {
                /*
                 * Firefox 3.6 fires the dragleave event on the previous element
                 * before firing dragenter on the next one so we introduce a delay
                 */
                setTimeout(function() {
                    collection = collection.not(event.target);
                    if (collection.length === 0) {
                        self.trigger('dndDragLeave');
                    }
                }, 1);
            });

            self.on('dragover', function(event) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    collection = collection.not(event.target);
                    if (collection.length === 0) {
                        self.trigger('dndDragOver');
                    }
                }, 1);
            });

            self.on('drop,dragdrop', function(event) {
                self.trigger('dndDragDrop');
            });
        });
    };

    $('.uploadDiv').dndhover().on({
        'dndDragEnter': function(event) {

            if(!$(".selectFile").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".selectFile").addClass("hide");
            }
            if($(".dropFile").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".dropFile").removeClass("hide");
            }

            event.stopPropagation();
        },
        'dndDragLeave': function(event) {

            if($(".selectFile").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".selectFile").removeClass("hide");
            }
            if(!$(".dropFile").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".dropFile").addClass("hide");
            }
        },
        'dndDragDrop': function(event) {
            alert('dropped');
            if(!$(".selectFile").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".selectFile").addClass("hide");
            }
            if(!$(".dropFile").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".dropFile").addClass("hide");
            }
            alert(event);
            event.preventDefault();
        },
        'dndDragOver': function(event) {
            if(!$(".selectFile").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".selectFile").addClass("hide");
            }
            if($(".dropFile").hasClass("hide")){
                $(".dropFile").removeClass("hide");
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to upload working code

Comment: This is main code where .uploadDiv will fire dndHoverDrop.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341021/6923146 and share your browser detail also

Comment: I have used it and write a new code please check above. but its not working. please give me the working code in answer or in comment.